# Unable to type in console app after restore from system tray using c#

Tags: c#, console-application, system-tray

I'm following this tutorial from this [Link](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/354327/Minimizing-Console-Window-to-System-Tray) and add menu but unable to type to console app after minimized to system tray and restoring it back.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetShellWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();

    static NotifyIcon notifyIcon;
    static IntPtr processHandle;
    static IntPtr WinShell;
    static IntPtr WinDesktop;
    static MenuItem HideMenu;
    static MenuItem RestoreMenu;

    static Thread notifyThread;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int Input;
        do
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Please select");
            Console.WriteLine("[1] Settings");
            Console.WriteLine("[2] View Messages");
            Console.WriteLine("[3] Run in background");
            Console.WriteLine("[4] Exit");

            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Input))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number only");
            }

            switch (Input)
            {
                case 1:
                    break;
                case 2:
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //notifyThread = new Thread(delegate ()
                    //{
                        notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
                        notifyIcon.Icon = new Icon("e_mail.ico");
                        notifyIcon.Text = "Email";
                        notifyIcon.Visible = true;

                        ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
                        HideMenu = new MenuItem("Hide", new EventHandler(Minimize_Click));
                        RestoreMenu = new MenuItem("Restore", new EventHandler(Maximize_Click));

                        menu.MenuItems.Add(RestoreMenu);
                        menu.MenuItems.Add(HideMenu);
                        menu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Exit", new EventHandler(CleanExit)));

                        notifyIcon.ContextMenu = menu;

                        Task.Factory.StartNew(Run);
                        processHandle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
                        WinShell = GetShellWindow();
                        WinDesktop = GetDesktopWindow();

                        ResizeWindow(false);

                        Application.Run();
                    //});
                    //notifyThread.Start();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Environment.Exit(-1);
                    break;
                default:
                    Input = 0;
                    break;
            }

        } while (Input == 0);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Listening to messages");
        while (true)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }


    private static void CleanExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        notifyIcon.Visible = false;
        Application.Exit();
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }


    static void Minimize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ResizeWindow(false);
    }


    static void Maximize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ResizeWindow(); 
    }

    static void ResizeWindow(bool Restore = true)
    {
        if (Restore)
        {
            RestoreMenu.Enabled = false;
            HideMenu.Enabled = true; 
          SetParent(processHandle, WinDesktop); 
        }
        else
        {
            RestoreMenu.Enabled = true;
            HideMenu.Enabled = false;
            SetParent(processHandle, WinShell);
        }
    }
```

If i select the number 3 it will minimize to system tray and there's a context menu on the icon that has an option to restore it, How can i allow to type back in console app after restoring it from system tray?

Comment: Any particular reason why you're not just doing this as a proper windows forms / wpf app?

Comment: I actually did this in windows forms but my client wanted me to do it using console app :(

Comment: The problem is that a console app doesn't have a window, so you're effectively having to find the dos window the app was started from, and minimise that. Find out more about the client requirements as to why, then maybe consider building an app that fakes a dos window with a black textbox and console font, if it's just cos they like the look of it

Comment: thank you for your explanation and suggestion.